# Using lambdas in command pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, lambda

I am looking to see how to adapt my existing command pattern implementation to JAVA 8 lambdas.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Command {

    public void execute(final Vehicle vehicle);
}

public class LeftCommand implements Command {

public void execute(final Vehicle vehicle){
    vehicle.turnLeft();
}

}

public class RightCommand implements Command {

public void execute(final Vehicle vehicle){
    vehicle.turnRight();
}

}
```

I have a class VehicleManager which calls processValue that looks to create commands based on string L or R that is passed to it as inputValue

```
processValues(Vehicle vehicle, String inputValue){
if("L".equals(inputValue){
  //create left command here
  Command cmd = (vehicle) -> vehicle.turnLeft(); //ERROR
  Command cmd = () -> vehicle.turnLeft(); //ERROR,expects 1 parameter vehicle to be passed
 }else{
 // create right command here
  Command cmd = (vehicle) -> vehicle.turnRight(); //ERROR
 }
}
```

I tried creating the command using lambdas as above, but it errors out saying vehicle is already defined.

1. Can you please advise me as to how I can create left and right command instances here using lambdas?
2. If I can successfully use lambdas above, then can I do away with my LeftCommand and RightCommand classes?

(I have checked quite a number of links on google, but I could not get this to work).

ADDED THIS POST SOME COMMENTS,

```
 private void processValues(String line, Vehicle vehicle) {
    List<Command> commands = new ArrayList<>();
    for(char c: line.toCharArray()){
        if(LEFT.equals(c)){
            commands.add(()-> vehicle.turnLeft());
        }else if(RIGHT.equals(c)){
            commands.add(()-> vehicle.turnRight());
        }else if(MOVE.equals(c)){
            commands.add(()-> rover.moveForward());
        }
    }
    commands.forEach((c) -> c.execute());
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: The thing between parentheses, `(vehicle)` is a new variable declaration that is the parameter for the target functional interface method. Since a variable with that name already exists in that context, you can't use it in the lambda expression parameter list. Use something else, `v` for example.

Comment: Your `processValues` method is confusing: you don't need a specific vehicle to create a Command... So a Command could be something like: `Command cmd = v -> v.turnLeft();` or `Command cmd = Vehicle::turnLeft`. Then you can apply it to a specific vehicle: `cmd.execute(vehicle);`...

Comment: @assylias I created something like this. Is this correct. Please check last section I added to my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of lambdas or method references in a Command Pattern will make your `RightCommand` and `LeftCommand` classes useless.

In your first example, should be applied to something like this:

```
private void processValues(Vehicle vehicle, String inputValue) {
  Command command;
  if ("Left".equals(inputValue)) {
    command = v -> v.turnLeft();  // <- With lambda expresion
  } else {
    command = Vehicle::turnRight; // <- With method reference
  }
  command.execute(vehicle);
}
```

A better explanation can be found in ["Using the command pattern with lambda expressions"](http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/12/using-the-command-pattern-with-lambda-expressions.html).